# Adding values into database with the use of primary and foreign keys

Tags: php, html, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Im trying to add the chosen values from my drop down menu into my database by using primary and foreign keys. Im trying to figure out how when the customer selects the drop down box option, the VALUE is entered into sql, which is the same number as room table primary. Would i somehow post the drop down box select id = rooID? Can anyone please help me with this.

Below is my makeabookingphp code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>Make a Booking</title> </head>
 <body>

<?php
 //function to clean input but not validate type and content
 function cleanInput($data) {  
 return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)));
 }

 //the data was sent using a formtherefore we use the $_POST instead of $_GET
 //check if we are saving data first by checking if the submit button exists in the array
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and !empty($_POST['submit']) and ($_POST['submit'] == 'Book')) {
 //if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //alternative simpler POST test    
include "config.php"; //load in any variables
$DBC = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);


 //prepare a query and send it to the server
 $query = 'SELECT room.roomID, room.roomname, room.roomtype, booking.bookingID, booking.roomID, booking.roomname
FROM room
INNER JOIN booking
ON room.roomID = booking.roomID';



 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. ".mysqli_connect_error() ;
    exit; //stop processing the page further
 };

 //validate incoming data - only the first field is done for you in this example - rest is up to you do

  $error = 0; //clear our error flag
  $msg = 'Error: ';
  if (isset($_POST['roomname']) and !empty($_POST['roomname']) and is_string($_POST['roomname'])) {
   $fn = cleanInput($_POST['roomname']); 
   $roomname = (strlen($fn)>50)?substr($fn,1,50):$fn; 
   //check length and clip if too big
   //we would also do context checking here for contents, etc       
   } else {
   $error++; //bump the error flag
   $msg .= 'Invalid'; //append eror message
   $roomname = '';  
   } 

   $roomname = cleanInput($_POST['roomname']);        

   $checkindate = cleanInput($_POST['checkindate']);        

   $checkoutdate = cleanInput($_POST['checkoutdate']);   

   $contactnumber = cleanInput($_POST['contactnumber']); 

   $bookingextras = cleanInput($_POST['bookingextras']);       
   
   //save the customer data if the error flag is still clear
   if ($error == 0) {
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO booking (roomname, checkindate, checkoutdate, contactnumber, bookingextras) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBC,$query1); //prepare the query
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssss', $roomname, $checkindate, $checkoutdate,$contactnumber,$bookingextras); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);    
    echo "<h2>Booking saved</h2>";        
} else { 
  echo "<h2>$msg</h2>".PHP_EOL;
}      
mysqli_close($DBC); //close the connection once done
}
?>
<h1>Make A Booking</h1>
<h2><a href='menu.php'>[Return to the main page]</a></h2>

<form method = "post" action = "processbooking.php">
<p>
<label for = "rooID">Room: (name, type, beds): </label>
<select id = "rooID" name = "rooID" required>
<option name = "" value = "" disabled selected>Select</option>
<option name = "1" value = "1">Kellie, S, 5</option>
<option name = "2" value = "2">Herman, D, 2</option>
<option name = "3" value = "3">Scarlett, D, 2</option>
<option name = "4" value = "4">Jelani, S, 5</option>
<option name = "5" value = "5">Sonya, S, 4</option>
<option name = "6" value = "6">Miranda, S, 2</option>
<option name = "7" value = "7">Helen, S, 2</option>
<option name = "8" value = "8">Octavia, D, 3</option>
<option name = "9" value = "9">Bernard, D, 5</option>
<option name = "10" value = "10">Dacey, D, 1</option>
</select>
</p> 

<p>
<label for="checkindate">Check in date: </label>
<input type="date" name="checkindate"required> 
</p>  
<p>
<label for="checkout">Check out date: </label>
<input type="date" name="checkoutdate"required> 
</p>  
<p>  
<label for="contactnumber">Contact number: </label>
<input type="tel" name="contactnumber" required> 
</p>
<p>
<label for="bookingextras">Booking extras: </label>
<input type="text" name="bookingextras" size="100" minlength="5" maxlength="200"  required> 
  </p> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book">
<a href="menu.php">[Cancel]</a>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Room table:

- roomID (PK)
- roomname
- description
- roomtype
- beds

Booking table:

- bookingID (PK)
- roomname
- checkindate
- checkoutdate
- contactnumber
- bookingextras
- roomID (FK)

Comment: Post your makeabooking.php file because that is where all the action is.

Comment: @jeff Ive added in to code for makeabooking.php so far, probably incorrect by a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code - hope it helps

```
<?php
 //function to clean input but not validate type and content
 function cleanInput($data) {  
 return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)));
 }

// STEP 1 -test if form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Book')) {
    // STEP 2. process the inputs
    // get inputs - clean or set a default if not supplied
   $roomID        = isset( $_POST['rooID'] )         ? cleanInput($_POST['rooID'])         : -1;                
   $checkindate   = isset( $_POST['checkindate'] )   ? cleanInput($_POST['checkindate'])   : "";        
   $checkoutdate  = isset( $_POST['checkoutdate'] )  ? cleanInput($_POST['checkoutdate'])  : "";   
   $contactnumber = isset( $_POST['contactnumber'] ) ? cleanInput($_POST['contactnumber']) : ""; 
   $bookingextras = isset( $_POST['bookingextras'] ) ? cleanInput($_POST['bookingextras']) : "";
    
    // STEP 3 validate/clean the inputs (don't trust anything coming in)
    // validate all the inputs according to business rules
    $error = 0;
    $errMsg  = [];
    if( roomID == -1 ) {
        $error++;
        $errMsg[] = "Room not selected";
    }
    // do all other inputs
    
    // proceed if no errors
    if( $error != 0 ) {
        // STEP 4 connect to the database
        // connect to the database
        include "config.php"; //load in any variables
        $DBC = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. ".mysqli_connect_error() ;
            exit; //stop processing the page further
        };      
        // STEP 5 check if the roomID is valid
        // if roomID is valid then continue
        $query = "SELECT roomID FROM roomTable WHERE roomID=".$roomID;
        $result = $DBC->query( $query ); // ???? check the syntax of this line
        if( $result ) { // something returned ???? check syntax
            // STEP 5 update the relevant table(s)
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO booking (roomID, checkindate, checkoutdate, contactnumber, bookingextras) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBC,$query1); //prepare the query
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'issss', $roomID, $checkindate, $checkoutdate,$contactnumber,$bookingextras); 
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   
            echo "<h2>Booking saved</h2>";
        }
    } else {
        // STEP 3.1 show user messages of what went wrong
        echo $errMsg;
    }
    mysqli_close($DBC); //close the connection once done
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help but it still isn't adding it to my database when i click book it just comes up with two warnings and two notices

Comment: what does it mean when the warning says mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in